# npm install giving several errors

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I have been using node and npm for a while without any problem on my Windows 10 pc. I was working on a project and had to use vite to setup react. It stated that my minimum node version should be higher so I upgraded it. But, after that, whenever I try to use npm install, I get the following errors

```
npm ERR! code ENOTDIR  
npm ERR! syscall mkdir  
npm ERR! path I:\\........\\node_modules\\eslint\\node_modules  
npm ERR! errno -4052  
npm ERR! ENOTDIR: not a directory, mkdir I:\\......\\node_modules\\eslint\\node_modules'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\\Users\\\*\*\*\*\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\\_logs\\202.............-debug-0.log
```

I have tried to force clean the cache, I have deleted and reinstalled node LTS several times, yet the problem persists.

I have looked at a lot of solutions I don't know how to resolve this.

Comment: Make sure you have write permission to the directory.

Comment: How do I check that? @sujeet